# Get wrong result by substituting through value

Tags: haskell

I have following function:

```
meh :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh [] _ = return []
meh (x:xs) f = do
  x' <- f x
  fmap ((:) x') (meh xs f)
```

then I try it out in prelude as follow and I've got:

```
*ExerciseMonad Control.Monad> meh [3,4,5] (\x -> Just x)
Just [3,4,5]
```

But I do expect `[Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]`.

To find out, what went wrong, I did substitution:

```
meh [3,4,5] (\x -> Just x) = Just [3,4,5]

meh (3:[4,5])] (\x -> Just x) =
  Just 3 <- (\3 -> Just 3)
  fmap ((:) (Just 3)) (meh [4,5] (\x -> Just x))

meh (4:[5])] (\x -> Just x) =
  Just 4 <- (\4 -> Just 4)
  fmap ((:) (Just 4)) (meh [5] (\x -> Just x))

meh ([5])] (\x -> Just x) =
  Just 5 <- (\5 -> Just 5]
  fmap ((:) (Just 5)) (meh [] (\x -> Just x))

meh [] _ = return []  


--all the way back
meh ([5])] (\x -> Just x) = fmap ((:) (Just 5)) []
meh (4:[5])] (\x -> Just x) = fmap ((:) (Just 4)) [Just 5] <- result [Just 4, Just 5]
meh (3:[4,5])] (\x -> Just x) = fmap ((:) (Just 3)) [Just 4, Just 5] <- result [Just 4, Just 5]
meh [3,4,5] (\x -> Just x) = [Just 3,Just 4, Just 5]
```

As you can see, the substitution does not match to the right result:

```
Just [3,4,5] != [Just 3,Just 4, Just 5]
```

My question, what did I wrong with the substitution? That I've got the wrong result?

Comment: `meh :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]` your function returns a `m [b]` not a `[m b]`

Comment: `(Functor m, Monad m)` is redundant; you only need to put `Monad m`, since `Functor` is a requirement of `Monad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the type, everything works fine

```
meh :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
```

If you're expecting `[Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]` you might need something like:

```
meh :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> [m b]
```

Or just

```
meh :: (Functor m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> [m b]
```

Because you don't need the monad instance if you're not going to join values.

```
meh' :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> [m b]
meh' [] _ = []
meh' (x:xs) f =
  (f x) : (meh' xs f)
```

Calling `meh' [3,4,5] Just` returns `[Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]`

Calling `meh [3,4,5] Just` returns `Just [3,4,5]`

Talking about a substitution (starting from the empty list):

`meh [] _ = Just []`, because `meh [] _ = return []` returns an empty list wrapped into a monadic structure (in this case `Maybe` monad)

```
meh (5:[]) (\x -> Just x) = do
  x' <- (\x -> Just x) 5
  fmap ((:) x') (meh [] (\x -> Just x))
```

In this step `x' <- (x -> Just x) 5` binds `x'` to `5`. That's why `meh [5] Just` transforms into `fmap ((:) 5) (Just [])` that equals `Just [5]`, rather than `fmap ((:) (Just 5)) []` which indeed equals `[Just 5]`

Answer (score 0):

As I commented before your type signature is wrong:
If you check the type for `[Just 1, Just 2, ...]` would be like `[m b]` not `m []`.

Also, you cant simplify your function to:

```
meh :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> [m b]
meh l f = fmap f l
```

Here you have a [life example](https://repl.it/KE28/0)

Your substitution is wrong on this step:

`x' <- f x`

Since you are working inside a monad you are binding (with `<-`) to `x'` the Value inside 
the monad (`Just` in this case) so 'x'' will be `3` (4, 5, ...) not `Just 3`